# How to create an enum/map of key values in Go

Tags: object, go, enums

I am new to Go and love it so far but it seems that I cannot find a simple solution to this.

I want to create a constant that I can reference in my code by Key and get its value

I have this:

```
const (
    DBName            = "goApi"
    UsersTable string = "users"
)
```

And would like to have a Tables constant variable that stores the value

Example:

```
var Tables = {
   UsersTable : "users",
   PostsTable : "posts"
}

//Somewhere else in the code
fmt.Println(Tables.UsersTable) //output "users"
```

How can I achieve this in Go?

Comment: A map cannot be a const. Your current `const ( ... )` declaration is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can declare as `const` in Go is limited to only the basic types like ints, strings, bools, etc. There is no way to declare non-basic types like structs, maps, slices, funcs, etc. as a `const`.

So to get to `Tables.UsersTable` you can either declare your `Tables` as a struct `var`:

```
var Tables = struct{
    UsersTable string
    PostsTable string
}{
    UsersTable: "users",
    PostsTable: "posts",
}
```

Note that since this is a variable and not a constant, there's nothing that protects the fields' values from being modified by malice or bug.

Or, the other option you have is to create a new package, name it `tables`, and in it declare your constants.

```
package tables

const (
    UsersTable = "users"
    PostsTable = "posts"
)
```

Then you can use it by simply importing the package

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "path/to/tables"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(tables.UsersTable)
}
```

Note that the first solution, if imported by another package will result in `fmt.Println(somepkg.Tables.UsersTable)` *(unless a `.` import is used)* which may not be what you're looking for, or maybe it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare enum like this:

```
const (
    Running = iota       // value --> 0
    Stopped              // value --> 1
    Rebooting            // value --> 2
    Terminated           // value --> 3
)
```

And map declaration is like this, too.
Hope that this can help u.

Comment: Hey @Bryant thanks for your answer. I am more interested in making a const variable that stores only constants regarding Tables that I could access with. ex: var Tables { UserTable: "users", PostTable: "posts" } . And try to access it with Tables.UserTable

Comment: i think you can not do that. if you make a const variable pointing to a map, it only means you cannot make this variable pointing to another map, but the key-value in the map can be changed, the key-value is not const.